# In Richard Scarry's Busytown books, does Lowly Worm have a family?

Tags: richard-scarry, busytown

In Richard Scarry's Busytown books, Lowly is always sleeping over at Huckle's house. What's the deal with that? Does Lowly have a family of his own?

Comment: Ooh, I used to love the Richard Scarry books as a kid. Lowly Worm was my favourite character :-D

Comment: I have a vague memory of a table with worms around it, but I can't pin down a book where that happened.

Comment: I'm not the only one with this question... https://www.nytimes.com/2014/10/08/books/richard-scarrys-best-lowly-worm-book-ever-and-100-things-that-make-me-happy.html

Comment: I recall a Scarry book stating that Lowly is a friend who occasionally sleeps over by Huckles house. Anyone have any idea which story that is?

Comment: I found it. See my new answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Lowly is a friend who SOMETIMES sleeps at Huckle's house, according to official Richard Scarry Canon.

[image]

> Their friend Lowly often comes to spend the night.

Comment: Ah OK, good find.

Answer (score 8):

He's not just "sleeping over" at Huckle's house; he actually *lives* there:

[image: Image from book]

> Everyone helps to make breakfast at the Cat family house where I live.

He seems to be a fully integrated (perhaps adopted?) part of the Cat family. See also how Mother Cat treats him like one of her own children:

[image: Another image]

> He left muddy footprints all over Mother Cat's clean floor. "Lowly," said Mother Cat. "You *know* you should never come into the house with a muddy foot."
>
> She had to give Lowly a bath. My! He's a slippery little fellow.
>
> Then she dried him off, and he got dressed for supper.
>
> At the supper table, everyone ate with his fork. Nobody ever eats with his fingers or his foot.
>
> After supper, Daddy gave everyone a piggyback ride to bed. Good night, all!

<sub>(I found these images [here](https://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/660/media/images/70128000/jpg/_70128994_lowlyworm2.jpg) and [here](https://static.wixstatic.com/media/cecdc6_9bc1eca9fbd14e08a2ca776e107d4ad5.jpg), but I'm not sure exactly which Scarry book they're from.)</sub>

As far as I know, Lowly is the only worm ever mentioned in the Busytown books. **His family, as far as we're concerned, is the Cat family.**

It's worth noting, though, that the Richard Scarry books don't invest much effort into striving for consistency. They're meant for young children, not nitpicking adults. For example, Lowly drives a car (in the shape of an apple) and joins a spaceflight to the moon - both activities normally reserved for adults - but he also goes to school together with Huckle, suggesting that he's meant to be a child. So don't expect to be able to analyse Scarry's worldbuilding in great detail; there will be all sorts of details which simply aren't addressed anywhere in the books.

Comment: The second image is from Richard Scarry's Please and Thank You Book https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/161422/richard-scarrys-please-and-thank-you-book-by-written-and-illustrated-by-richard-scarry/